# Can the pre-image of a non-measurable set be measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, functions, definition, examples-counterexamples

Here is the original question:

Suppose we define function $f$ that is measurable in the Caratheodory sense.

**Main Question:**

Can the pre-image of a non-measurable set under $f$ be measurable in the sense of caratheodory?

**Attempt:**

I'm not sure how to approach the main question but we will attempt a solution by taking the contrapositive of this question:

> Can the image of a measurable set under $f$ be non-measurable?

Due to my lack of formal training beyond Intro to Advanced Math, I couldn't figure out if the contrapositive is true; however, from [Royden in *Real Analysis*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888727/cantor-lebesgue-function-maps-a-measurable-set-onto-non-measurable-set-proof-ve), if the Cantor-Lebesgue function is $f$, there exists a measurable subset in the domain of $f$ (i.e. the cantor set) whose image under $f$ is non-measurable.

Is the second question *infact* the contrapositive of the **main question**? If not, how do we prove the *main question* is wrong?

**Final Note/Motivation:**

I wanted to make sure the [*main question* in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699353/does-this-measurable-function-exist-and-satisfy-my-motivation) (specifically criteria 3.) helps to satisfy the motivation of [that post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699353/does-this-measurable-function-exist-and-satisfy-my-motivation).

In other words, I want to find a function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ whose graph is dense, and *somewhat*  but not *too evenly distributed*, in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$

Comment: If the image of a measurable set is non-measurable, that doesn't mean that the preimage of the non-measurable set is measurable, because there may have been other sets that map into our non-measurable set.

Comment: @S.L. I see, but is my main question true?

Comment: a silly answer to the question in the title would be to take a constant function and the preimage under a non-measurable set containing the single point in the image... (which will then just be the domain, measurable)

Comment: @GeorgeCoote Thanks. I wanted to make sure that criteria 3. in the main question of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699353/does-this-measurable-function-exist-and-satisfy-my-motivation) helps satisfy the motivation of the post.

Comment: @GeorgeCoote I don't find this answer to be silly at all :)