# If the graph of a measurable function is dense in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, can the pre-image of a non-measurable set be measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, functions, definition, examples-counterexamples

Follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705924/can-the-pre-image-of-a-non-measurable-set-be-measurable):

Suppose we define function $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ that is measurable in the Caratheodory sense, using the Lebesgue Outer Measure, and the graph of $f$ is dense in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

**Main Question:**

Can the pre-image of a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ (under $f$) be measurable in the sense of caratheodory, using the Lebesgue Outer Measure?

**Attempt:**

I'm not sure how to approach the main question. I attempted a solution by taking the *proposed* contrapositive of the main question:

> Can the image of a measurable set under $f$ be non-measurable?

but this isn't the contrapositive as stated from @S.L.'s comment to the [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705924/can-the-pre-image-of-a-non-measurable-set-be-measurable).

Furthermore, due to my lack of formal training beyond Intro to Advanced Mathematics, I don't know the proper answer to the main question. (However, I do know non-measurable sets can't be explicitly defined *and* vary by their Lebesgue Outer Measure.)

Even then, I'm not sure if this means the pre-image of a non-measurable set under $f$ (even for continuous, non-constant $f$) can never be measurable, proving the main question wrong.

**Final Note/Motivation:**

I wanted to make sure the [*main question* in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699353/does-this-measurable-function-exist-and-satisfy-my-motivation) (specifically criteria 3.) to help satisfy the motivation of [the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699353/does-this-measurable-function-exist-and-satisfy-my-motivation).

In other words, I want to find a function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ whose graph is dense, and *somewhat*  but not *too evenly distributed*, in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

If the main question for this post is wrong, I would like someone to rewrite the main question in [*this post*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699353/does-this-measurable-function-exist-and-satisfy-my-motivation) to satisfy the motivation.

Comment: What is "measurable in the sense of Carathedory?"

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Measurable in the [sigma algebra of caratheodory measurable sets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion).

Comment: That requires an outer measure.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Use the Lebesgue Outer Measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same function given by https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4706564/1184648 also works as an example here. Take a Vitali set $V$ with $V \cap \mathbb{Q}=\{1\}$. Then the function $f$ defined as in the answer to that post satisfies $f^{-1}(V)=\emptyset$.

Comment: Do you think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4706564/1176963), satisfies [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699353/does-this-measurable-function-exist-and-satisfy-my-motivation)? If so, be sure to give it an upvote. I don't know if the answer is correct or not.